# How do I add text to the end of webBrowser1 URL C#

Tags: c#, javascript, url

I am trying to disable javascript but I found something I can add to the URL to prevent it.

```
?no-script=true
```

How can I add this to the end of every URL that loads in `webBrowser1`?

Comment: this will not have any use unless the server whose URL you're requesting is actually handling the query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can simply handle the 'Navigating' event and redirect the Browser appropriately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx

> Occurs before the WebBrowser control navigates to a new document.

If the URL does not end with ?no-script=true', redirect it.

It's worth noting that '?no-script=true' isn't really something you can depend on.  Many (most) sites won't honor your request and you'll still get javascript.